# how do i send saved data to an email address

Tags: java, android, edit

I have created a custom feedback form that I wish to implement but i have come up stuck. I have the code in place apart from how to save data entered and then by pressing the send button i want to send information to a particular email address. Please Help? code below?

```
package com.sasquatchapps.hydraquip10.sasquatchapps;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void sendFeedback(View button) {


        EditText nameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextName);
        String name  = nameField.getText().toString();

         EditText emailField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextEmail);
        String email = emailField.getText().toString();

        EditText feedbackField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextFeedbackBody);
        String feedback = feedbackField.getText().toString();

        CheckBox responseCheckbox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.CheckBoxResponse);
        boolean bResponse = responseCheckbox.isChecked();

    }



}
```

Comment: could you please let me know what is the error you are facing

Comment: Whats your problem? Did you getting any error?

Comment: No error when i run the app i fill all fields in and hit the send button and nothing happens. What i need to now is how to get the send button to work by sending the information entered to a email address

Answer (score 0):

```
try this by using intent 
Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);  
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{ to});  
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);  
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);  

//need this to prompts email client only  
email.setType("message/rfc822");  

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));  

otherwise you need to implement you owncode to sand a email.
```